# "Cannot Read Property Location of Undefined" Error with React Router

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, navbar, router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a simple React storefront and there is a bug with my router setup. I've provided screenshots of the relevant files and the error message. The file flow for the router is **Navbar.js** -> **App.js** -> **Index.js**. I haven't done any routing in a long time, so I apologize if there are details I'm leaving out or something I'm not explaining correctly. Any suggestions will help.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Router" component is only needed once like you have it in index.js

Navbar.js does not need the "Router" component so you can remove it. Also your import of the "Router" is wrong in Navbar.js (its correct in index.js)

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this.props` in React class components. `this.props.history.location`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Router component is telling us to start listen to location. So in your App.js, start by including an import of useLocation to your react-router-dom. Then make a useEffect listen to the location so Router always can know which location you are on, and thereby determin which Route component to show.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentPath = location.pathname;
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  }, [location]);
  return ( ...
}
```